# How to clear 'text-watcher' previous value in android?

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am using  **onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)** of Text watcher which is attached to **MultiAutoCompleteTextView** in my activity.

When I type some text for eg. 'nik' in **MultiAutoCompleteTextView** , then drop down list opens with some suggested sentences, when one item is selected from the drop down eg. (nikhil kaushik;) and then I do back press too delete a character, every thing gets deleted expect initial search value 'Nik'.

How to prevent this, I don't want every thing to get deleted, only last character should be deleted from 'nikhil kaushik;'.

Request you to please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Set empty string `""` in the text view at the end of your `onTextChanged` method or Override `afterTextChanged` method of `text watcher` and set text view with empty string.

Comment: It is still not working, the variable **s** hold nik searched value, it directly jumped over last value somewhere it retains old value

Comment: You should reset that value to "" .